# Searching for XML node at unknown depth with ESQL

Tags: xml, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

Assume the following 2 xml payloads

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>target value</c>
    </b>
</a>
```

and

```
<a>
    <c>target value</c>
<a>
```

Is it possible to use ESQL to retrieve tag `<c>`'s value regardless of depth it appears in? I have seen blogs that seem to suggest to use the `select` statment to do so, but none that have explicitly showed me how.

Answer (score 2):

You have to construct a depth search with a recursive algorithmen.

```
CREATE FUNCTION NavigateTree(IN root REFERENCE) RETURNS CHAR BEGIN

    DECLARE element REFERENCE TO root;
    MOVE element FIRSTCHILD;

    WHILE LASTMOVE(element) DO

        DECLARE nameField CHARACTER FIELDNAME(element);

        -- Cechar element
        IF nameField = 'c' THEN
            -- Return the Value
            RETURN element;

        ELSE
            IF CheckLeaf(element) IS FALSE THEN
                DECLARE child REFERENCE TO element;
                MOVE child FIRSTCHILD;
                RETURN NavegarArvore(child);
            END IF;

            MOVE element NEXTSIBLING;
        END IF;

    END WHILE;

    RETURN NULL;

END;


CREATE FUNCTION CheckLeaf(IN element REFERENCE) RETURNS BOOLEAN BEGIN

    DECLARE leaf BOOLEAN FALSE;

    DECLARE elemCheck REFERENCE TO element;
    MOVE elemCheck FIRSTCHILD;

    IF LASTMOVE(elemCheck) IS FALSE THEN
        SET leaf = TRUE;
    END IF;

    RETURN leaf;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

'Only' a select statement won't work for this purpose; it works on arrays as if every element in the array is a row in a table and each field inside every element is a column value. For example
`select T1.phone from InputRoot.SomePath.contacts[] as T1;`

As Rafael suggested, a recursive function is the solution in this case but watch out to the possible depth of your tree or your add an if statement to Rafael code to exit searching a path if it exceeded a predefined limit.